# (Chrome Extension) Local Folder Access

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

For around nearly 2 months now, I've been trying to find a way to access a user's local folder through their permission, but to no avail. I've read that the reason why there isn't a straightforward way is due to security issues, Manifest V3, and so on.....

Basically, what I'm trying to create is a music player extension in Chrome (FYI: This is my first time creating a Chrome extension), and I want the user to select a local folder (path) which has mp3 files included within it so that the extension can load and play the songs within the folder.

The way I planned it was that after the user selected a folder, each MP3 file from that folder would be stored into an array so that the extension could play through them. However aforementioned, it's been difficult to try and access local folders (and also files for that matter).

I've read that one way to access files was through building a Chrome app and having it communicate with the extension, but is there possibly any other way that possibly works?

Comment: There is [file system access api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) which you can probably use

Comment: Problem is, is that I don't think it works with Chrome Extensions unfortunately. When I tried it, nothing happened

Comment: @wOxxOm that's what I said. Hence [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73543839/is-browsers-extension-considered-a-secure-context?noredirect=1#comment129873795_73543839) I thought that maybe extensions aren't in the secure context because OP can't use the file system.

Comment: @Konrad Linowski err....I think you posted your message in the wrong thread by the looks of it lol

Comment: @wOxxOm removed their comment